# Trim column to fixed length in file in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk

My file contains a data in following format. Third and fourth fields are date. I want to keep just the date portion of these fields and remove the time part. Second fraction is always ".0Z".

Input:

```
1,2,2012-04-11T00:06:52.0Z,2012-04-11T00:06:52.0Z
```

Output:

```
1,2,2012-04-11,2012-04-11
```

Thanks
Jitendra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sed` like this:

```
sed 's/T[^,]*//g' file
```

Or with `awk`:

```
awk '{ gsub(/T[^,]*/,"") }1' file
```

---

Or if the first two fields could contain the letter 'T':

```
sed 's/\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^T]*\)[^,]*\([^T]*\).*/\1\2/' file
```

Or with `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{ sub(/T.*/,"",$3); sub(/T.*/,"",$4) }1' OFS=, file.txt
```

Results:

```
1,2,2012-04-11,2012-04-11
```

Comment: Yes, first two fields can contain letter T. I will try your awk solution.

Comment: @steve The last awk command should be the only right answer, provided that first two fields may contain `T`. I have posted a similar solution, but yours are more concise, so I deleted mine. I just cannot figure out the usage of `1` in your awk expression. Does that means a boolean `true` to print line?

Comment: @HuiZheng: Added another solution using `sed`. It's shorter so perhaps it's more concise. That's an argument in itself. Anyway, regarding the `awk` command, adding `1` on the end simply enables printing by default. So it's just shorthand for `print $0` unconditionally. HTH.

Comment: @steve I can imagine what `1` is doing, but I just cannot find that usage in AWK reference. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, a lone `1` is the Awk idiom to print unconditionally. An awk script is a sequence of *condition* { *commands* } where both the conditions are optional (default to unconditionally execute commands) and the commands (default action is to print the current input line). Thus a single expression which evaluates to true causes the input to be printed.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly with awk. I didn't try sed solution. I still have to understand how it works though.

Answer (score 2):

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed 's/T[^,]*//g' input_file
```

### Output:

```
1,2,2012-04-11,2012-04-11
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use perl to solve this if that's available in your environment.

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d+),(\d+),(.*)T.*,(.*)T.*/\1,\2,\3,\4/' < yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the first two fields may contain `T`, `awk` should be a better choice than `sed`:

```
awk -F, '{sub("T.*","",$3); sub("T.*","",$4); print}' OFS=, input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F, -ane '$F[3]=~s/T.*//g;$F[2]=~s/T[^,]*//g;print join ",",@F;' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use both comma and "T" as field separators. Then, `$4` and `$6` are the time fields. You can then discard the fields you don't want

```
awk -F '[,T]' -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$5}'
```